# Sunspot and Advanced Association Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, solr, sunspot

My app has `Machines` that have and belong to many `Specifications`

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :specs
```

Specifications have both `field` (width, weight, capacity, horsepower) and `value` attributes.

The search is done entirely through Solr through Sunspot.

I'd like to be able to find a Machine based on its Specifications, such as find all machines with Width greater than 50.

I know I can index `spec_field` and `spec_value`separately, but it will filter for specs with value more than 50, which could include fields I don't want, such as height or capacity (so searching for width > 50 will yield capacity > 50 in results).

Ideally, I'd like to assign each Specification of a Machine to its own indexed field along with its value, so that my index has field such as "height" or "weight", but the specifications are flexible, and some machines have one set of specs while another machine has a different set, so it doesn't look like it can work out.

Can it even be done with Solr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution Found**

The Solution I found was to use "Dynamic Fields" as described [here](http://outoftime.github.com/)

INDEXING

```
dynamic_integer :specs do
  specs.inject({}) do |hash,spec|
    hash.merge(spec.spec_field.label.to_sym => spec.value)
  end
end
```

QUERY

```
  dynamic :specs do
    if params[:specs].present?
      for spec in params[:specs]
        case spec[:condition]
          when "gt"
            with(spec[:field]).greater_than(spec[:value])
          when "lt"
            with(spec[:field]).less_than(spec[:value])
          else
            with(spec[:field],spec[:value])
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

SOLR keeps looking better and better to me!

Comment: +1 If I could send you many many reputation points, I would. This is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a method that returns TRUE for your specified number range and string values and then index that boolean.

```
def width_greater_than_50
  (field == "width") && (value > 50)
end
```

You would then pass the symbol `:width_greater_than_50` as the thing you want to index.

Comment: How will it work? I understand this will index whether or not the machine has a width over 50, but now I need to search for "capacity" over 200 let's say. I can't index all the possible search queries.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood; I thought this was an indexing problem.  It sounds like you have more of a querying problem.  Is that correct?

Comment: I see it as both indexing and querying problem, mainly because I have no clue how to do it... If you take a look at solr.CurrencyField, you see how it is stored in "amount,currency" format, and then somehow it is able to search for it. I feel like this a direction where I should be looking at, but still, no clue.